# Frequency of a number in array faster than linear time

Tags: arrays, big-o, frequency

Find the frequency of a number in array **in less than *O(n)* time**.

```
Array 1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,2
Input 5
Output 3
```

```
Array 1,1,1,1
Input 1
Output 4
```

Comment: if the array is not sorted you need to see each number atleast once which ever way you find the frequency, in a randomly arranged array finding the frequency without looking at each element is not possible

Answer (score 1):

If the *only* information you have is an unsorted array (as your test data seems to indicate), you *cannot* do better than `O(n)` in finding the frequency of a given value. There's no getting around that.

In order to achieve a better time complexity, there are a variety of ways.

---

One would be to keep the array sorted (or a parallel sorted array if you didn't want to change the order). This way, you could use a binary search to find the first item with the given value then sequentially scan that portion to get a count. While the *worst* case (all items the same and that value is what you're looking for) is still `O(n)`, it will tend toward `O(log n)` average case.

Note that sorting the data each time before looking for a value will not work since that will almost certainly push you *above* the `O(n)` limit. The idea would be to sort only on item insertion.

---

Another method, provided your domain (possible values) is limited, is to maintain the actual frequencies of those values separately. For example, if the domain is limited to the numbers one through a hundred, have a separate array containing the frequency of each value.

When the list is empty, all frequencies are zero. Whenever you add or remove an item, increment or decrement the frequency for that value. This would make frequency extraction a quick `O(1)` operation.

---

But, as stated, both these solutions require extra/modified data to be maintained. Without that, you cannot do better than `O(n)` since you will need to examine every item in the array to see if it matches the value you're looking for.